# "Amazon Rekognition experienced a service issue" can't train a model

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I want to train a model using these pictures as training data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n35jne68hjws2d4/runes.zip?dl=0

Unfortunately this is failing training every single time that I try to train.

I am planning for my test data to be something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyXpK.jpg

And this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMkQh.jpg

I have succeeded in labeling everything I need and my understanding is that this should be viable (or does anybody have any feedback on how my data should look like for this to work? Maybe I'm doing something wrong?)

I've tried to train my Rekognition model five times and it's failed every time with "Amazon Rekognition experienced a service issue. It seems to me that this is an internal failure in the service but I wanted to ask if somebody has run into the same kind of issue too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a server-side problem, and I had to contact support to get it fixed!